# VS Code is consuming lot of memory. Why?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently installed Visual Studio Code on my Ubuntu-20.04 (4GB RAM). It was consuming about 200-300 MB, without any extensions installed (which, acc. to me is too much).
I installed Python extension from Microsoft. It seemed like a small extension in the beginning, but after installation, it is literally gobbling up all the memory (~1.5GB!).
Please refer to the link below.
Why is this happening? Is there any issue with the extension, or with VS Code itself?
[This is my system readings once the extension is up and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiK5w.png)
Thank you.

Comment: That is normal.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Is there any way to use this extension without freezing my machine? Or should I just stop using it?

Comment: VS Code is written in JavaScript/TypeScript so it takes a lot off system resources. If you dont have enough system resources change it to some other ide.

Comment: Okay, thank you @Eka

Comment: VS Code is an Electron app, and high RAM usage is common with the Electron framework.

Answer (score -2):

So, your vscode extension is taking up 1.5 GB of RAM. And you want to know why.

Actually the python extension you installed is communicating with the microsoft servers to provide you with intellisense (intelligently autocompletes code and highlights errors) in realtime.

As it is evident from your screenshot that the culprit is *Microsoft.Python.LanguageServer*.

`Language Server is a special kind of Visual Studio Code extension that powers the editing experience for many programming languages. With Language Servers, you can implement autocomplete, error-checking (diagnostics), jump-to-definition, and many other language features supported in VS Code.`

My suggestion:

I would suggest you use vscodium, it is an open-source alternative to vs code. Basically it is same as vscode just replacing the proprietary bits from microsoft. You can also get the python extension and it doesn't hog down the ram that much.

Attesting the screenshot to prove my point.

[image]

Use this command to install vscodium

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get codium
```

My system configuration

core i5 8th gen

8 GB ram

Parrot Security OS 4.10 (parrot is more resource hungry than ubuntu).

EDIT: Now the consumption is reduced from 1.5 GB to around 600 Mb after switching to codium. I think its a win-win.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would defenitely try it out.

Comment: Tried some extensions in codium like Microsoft's extension for Java. But the memory consumption was similar to that of vs code (~600MB). And also, since my reputation is less than the min reputation required for voting, it won't be reflected publicly ;).

Comment: In the screenshot you shared the memory consumed is 1.5 GB. So, i think 600mb is far too less.

Comment: And no worries for the upvote, but mark the answer as correct if you want.